# Difference between SublimeLinter-* and SublimeLinter-contrib-* packages

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimelinter

There doesn't seem to be any good documentation or explanation for the difference between `SublimeLinter-*` and `SublimeLinter-contrib-*` packages.

What difference, if any, does this naming schema imply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SublimeLinter-*` packages are provided by the same people who made the Sublime Linter package, while `SublimeLinter-contrib-*` packages are third-party contributions. In other words: all `SublimeLinter-*` are published at [github.com/SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter), contributed linters by different users.